# Python win32com opening Excel with Bloomberg plugin

Tags: python, excel, win32com, bloomberg

I'm trying to automate construction of an Excel 2007 spreadsheet that uses the Bloomberg plugin to pull down live prices. The problem is that when I open Excel through win32com the Bloomberg plugin does not load (so all of the formulas end up with "#NAME?" errors).

Manually uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin works, but copying the VBA code from the recorded macro leads to a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error. I can click the End button and everything runs fine, but I want to have this fully automated.

My code is:

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
MainWorkBook = xl.Workbooks.Add(1)
xl.AddIns("Bloomberg Excel Tools").Installed = False
xl.AddIns("Bloomberg Excel Tools").Installed = True
```

Setting DisplayAlerts = False doesn't catch the runtime error.

Answer (score 7):

you have to open the bloomberg.xla file with something like:

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
xl = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/BloombergUI.xla')
```

see here for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.addin.aspx